# Hibernate: virtual column

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm looking for a way to associate a entity with another entity purely through hibernate (no extra relation db column mappings) and not requiring separate DAO calls. I searched around for a solution and the only thing I could find was `@Formula`
 but I could not get it to work. Consider:

```
@Entity
class CommonEntity {
   @MagicAnnotation("maybe with HQL?")
   private SuperEntity superEntity;
}

@Entity
class SuperEntity { }
```

What this means is that sometimes `CommonEntity` is a `SuperEntity` and I want to have a getter on the POJO itself so it has access the `SuperEntity` via a simple `get()`. Is there any way to do this cleanly so that when I do something like `commonEntityDAO.get(1L);` where 1L IS a SuperEntity, then the entity will be set?

The tables in the database would look like:

```
table common_entity ( common_entity_id int primary key, name string );
table super_entity ( super_entity_id int primary key, extra_field string, common_entity_id int );
```

Comment: You say that CommonEntity IS A SuperEntity but in your example CommonEntity HAS A SuperEntity.

Comment: How would it look in the database?

Comment: I guess he tries to express the "is a" with a "has a" (odd indeed)

Comment: Yeah, I can't control the schema unfortunately but it is implemented as IS A with disjoint tables. I'll edit in what the tables might look like.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an *is a* relationship, this is a primary candidate for inheritance. Depending on the database representation you like there are multiple inheritance strategies. [check this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-implementation-patterns-mapping)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply use `@OneToOne`? Your database schema looks suitable for it.

```
@Entity 
class CommonEntity {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "commonEntity")
    private SuperEntity superEntity;
}  

@Entity 
class SuperEntity { 
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "common_entity_id")
    private CommonEntity commonEntity;
}
```

Note that in this case you need a bidirectional relationship with `SuperEntity` being an owning side, since it holds the foreign key.